# Python Script closes when opening

Tags: python

So I am making a KeyLogger but when I open it. It just closes again, I have tried to do the `Time.Sleep()` it didn't work. So is there a way I can make it wait until it's closed without it interrupting with my KeyLogger?

```
import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count
    print("[0] pressed".format(key))

#def sendToRequestBin():


def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: how are you running it? your script is working for me.

Comment: @Ronald Das I'm just double pressing the file on my Desktop. Not quite sure if it's the right way to run it tho

Comment: @lasseesharp you generally run python files, by typing `python filename` on your terminal(mac/linux) , or if in windows, you have to use cmd

Comment: you can use the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` (first line of your script) if you run it on Linux. (https://askubuntu.com/questions/716280/why-do-some-python-scripts-begin-with-usr-bin-env-python)

Comment: @Ronald Das yeps tank yu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With shebang on Linux:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count
    print("[0] pressed".format(key))

    #def sendToRequestBin():


def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
         return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

alternatively you can write a bash (or on Win a .bat) to do the call:

*runscript.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 yourScript.py
```

this script must be set run able by `chmod +x runscript.sh`

Or on Windows

*runscript.bat*

```
@ECHO OFF
python yourScript.py
ECHO Congratulations! Your first batch file executed successfully.
PAUSE
```